# Por que cuando llamo a boostrap para aplicar una funcion se me daña todo el CSS

Tags: html, css, html5, bootstrap, css3

Hola como están? Tengo una pregunta
Quiero agregarle a un login.php que hice, la opción de validar que los campos si se hayan llenado.
Entonces uso boostrap para esto(https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/validation/), cuando se lo agrego a mi login.php si funciona lo de la validación pero se me dañan los estilos que ya le he aplicado a mi login.php desde mi index.css, se que se dañan porque al llamar a
`<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">` estoy llamando un cdn que es un .css y este le da sus propiedades a mi html.
Mi pregunta es ¿Como hago para que no me dañe los estilos que ya le he aplicado a mi login.php al integrar la funcionalidad de boostrap was-validated?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Es simple. Tu tienes estilos en tu archivo index.css donde estás aplicando estilo a varios elementos. Al llamar a `<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` lo que ocurre es reemplazar y/o mezclar tus estilos de index.css con los de CDN.

Entonces, te sugeriría dos cosas que a mi me han funcionado cuando me ha pasado esto:

1. Cuando llames a los estilos, primero llama al CDN y luego a index.css, además, modifica tus estilos de index.css agregando el atributo !important al final de cada seleccion, para forzar al estilo a que se aplique.

ejemplo:

```
#validationCustom01{ background-color: #C3C3C3 !important; }
```

2. Descarga el archivo de CDN y edítalo (es algo tedioso pero funciona). Luego de descargarlo llamalo desde tu directorio y no desde la url de la web cdn.

Al editarlo, compara que elementos estan llamandose en cada archivo y comenta los que no se van a usar por ejemplo:

SI EN INDEX.CSS tienes:

```
.valid-feedback{display:block;width:100%;}
```

EN CDN tienes esta linea:

```
.valid-feedback{display:none;width:100%;margin-top:.25rem;font-size:.875em;color:#198754}
```

elige que propiedad no vas a utilizar y comentala así [Ejemplo suponiendo que no vas a utilizar atributos del estilo de CDN para la clase .valid-feedback

```
.valid-feedback{/*display:block;*/ width:90%;}
```

Puedes ayudarte en tu editor de código buscando de forma rápida el elemento a localizar presionando tu tecla F3, te abrirá un input de búsqueda

Comment: Aunque la respuesta soluciona la pregunta del OP, no puedo pasar por alto que, **ambas soluciones son muy malas prácticas**, el uso de `!important` debería ser para casos extremos. Y modificar un framework como Bootstrap nunca es una buena opción, mantenerlo a futuro será un dolor de cabeza, sin sentido, para eso crea una hoja de estilos propia.

Comment: Dicho esto, una mejor opción sería nombrar las clases propias de tu `login.php`, con etiquetas identificables dentro de tu hoja de estilos. Por ejemplo: Si en tu código tienes `<div class="container">` y NO quieres que Bootstrap lo modifique, reemplázalo por algo como `<div class="mi-container">` o simplemente `<div class="contenedor">`. Con esto puedes estilizar con clases propias y evitas la mala práctica de tocar el framework CSS